# XML question in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

In one of my sql scripts, I need to execute a stored procedure with the following xml string

```
<Collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Field>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute Name="CODE1" IsRequired="true" Order="1" IsVisible="true"/>
            <Attribute Name="CODE2" IsRequired="true" Order="2" IsVisible="true"/>
        </Attributes>
        <Rows>
            <Row ProductState="5">
                <Items>
                    <Item Name="PROD1" SendCustomer="false"/>
                    <Item Name="PROD2" SendCustomer="false"/>
                </Items>
            </Row>
        </Rows>
    </Field>
</Collection>
```

I get the `Attribute` and the `Item` information from different tables. I am writing a generic function in which you pass an ID and returns this XML string that is used by the SQL script to execute the stored procedure

Sometimes, I need to override the attribute values of some elements like `SendCustomer`. My initial thought was to deserialize this to a temp table, update the temp table with the override value and then serialize it back to XML.

So, essentially, the entire process boils down to:

1. Query tables, serialize to XML in the function
2. Deserialze XML, store in temp table
3. Override values if necessary
4. Serialze from table to XML again

Is there a more elegant way in sql server 2005 to do this entire process?

Answer (score 1):

The XML datatype actually can be modified using XQuery. See [the modify() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx).

```
declare @x XML;
select @x = N'<Collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Field>
        <Attributes>
                <Attribute Name="CODE1" IsRequired="true" Order="1" IsVisible="true"/>
                <Attribute Name="CODE2" IsRequired="true" Order="2" IsVisible="true"/>
        </Attributes>
        <Rows>
                <Row ProductState="5">
                        <Items>
                                <Item Name="PROD1" SendCustomer="false"/>
                                <Item Name="PROD2" SendCustomer="false"/>
                        </Items>
                </Row>
        </Rows>
    </Field>
</Collection>';

set @x.modify(N'replace value of 
    (/Collection/Field/Rows/Row/Items/Item[@Name="PROD2"]/@SendCustomer)[1]
    with "true"');

select @x;
```

Comment: Can you explain how the JQuery solution would fit into the question i had? Thanks

Comment: What is JQuery? My answer is Transact-SQL.